# SQL Server Date Conversion from Date to NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, import, excel-2007

I have requirement to import data from Excel into SQL Server 2008. The table into which the data is being imported contains a column `FIELDVALUE` which is of `NVARCHAR` datatype. All the date in the column `FieldValue` are stored in this format - `1393459200000`.

Now I have an Excel sheet with a date column in the format of `dd/MMM/yy`. Now I need to convert the date values in the Excel sheet to the 13 digit date format before I import them.

It would be great if you can suggest a method in Excel or any formula to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your number looks like a Unix date, which is the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

In Excel, you can reconstruct the date as:

```
 DATE(1970, 1, 1)+1393459200000/(1000*60*60*24)
```

You will want to format this as a date in Excel, otherwise it might look like `41697`.

EDIT:

To go the other way, reverse the formula:

```
DATE(2014, 2, 27)-DATE(1970, 1, 1))*24*60*60*1000
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But my requirement is the other way round.  I have a date and I need to convert it to UNIX date.